# How to work with JSON object after it has been passed from views.py in django?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

Consider a django model which stores the name, phone number and address of people.

To allow users to edit its contents, I have created an edit form in html template using **bootstrap modals**. I want to provide an option to the user to *'leave the field blank to retain old information'* (which is not the problem).

Along with this, I would also like to display the current information of each field as present in the database (as a placeholder value of the `<input>` tag).

In order to do that, I have created a 'context' dictionary in views.py which contains the data to be sent.

My question is, how do I send this dictionary from views.py to an html template **without rendering any html page** and how to parse this data on the template.

**Note:** I don't want to render any new page since I am using the bootstrap modal for the edit form.

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using Django forms for this? It would make it easier, and it's entirely possible to do it with the bootstrap css. If you really need to do it by passing JSON to the front end separately to the HTML template, you will need to use some javascript. There are many ways to do that, but for a basic starting point you might look at jQuery's ajax.

Comment: did u tried rest framework Response, you can send the context from view.py